# 2d array holding objects of one class in another class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I would like to create a 2d array ( the way its done in the block commented out below) which holds Cell objects.However i dont want to create this array in Cell class but in a Game class. I'm not sure how to do it? If i just put that in game class then i get an error of unknown class.In c++ an include would do but in java i'm quite new...

```
public class Cell{  

    public int positionX;
    public int positionY;
    public int valueOfCell = 0;
    /*    
    Cell[][] array = new Cell[12][12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
             array[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
        }
    }
    */

    public Cell getCell() {

    }

    public void setCell(Cell object,int Nvalue) {
        object.valueOfCell=Nvalue;
    }
}
```

EDIT: All classes are in one package

Comment: The java equivalent of ```include``` is ```import```, but that shouldn't be necessary as long as both classes are in the same package.

Comment: How are you compiling? IDE or command line?

Comment: IntelliJ. Now the only problem is with for loop it seems, i get an "unexpected token" error and "unknown class i", "identifier expected" and "unnecessary semicolon"

Comment: Ah, that is actually just a syntax error, ItelliJ probably can't find the ```Cell``` class because it doesn't compile. So there is no ```.class``` file to use.

Comment: Now everything is okay with Cell and imports and such however i can't see any syntax error in this for loop? Maybe i have been staring at this code for too long..

Comment: Eclipse swallows it, and I don't have IntelliJ. But it might be iffy about the blank line you have after the first ```for(...)``` statement.

Comment: Nope, i have also tried a ton of different versions of writing it so far :( it still treats int i as a class

Comment: Oh wait a minute... the code is not inside any method, that is illegal. You should either put the for loops in ```Cell```'s constructor, or in a ```static {...}``` block.

Comment: Static block helped,i used it instead of constructor since i create an array in Game class not in Cell class now. Thank you very much for help :)

Answer (score 1):

While assigning new instance of Cell to array,  int i and int j are passed in the constructor i.e. new Cell(i, j) but there is no constructor with two parameters defined in Cell.java. Also, as mentioned above the getCell method is not returning anything when the return type is declared to be of Type Cell. Cell.java can be modified as below:

```
public class Cell {

public int positionX;
public int positionY;
public int valueOfCell = 0;

public Cell(int i, int j) {
    this.positionX = i;
    this.positionY = j;
}

public Cell getCell() {
    return this;
}

public void setCell(Cell object, int Nvalue) {
    object.valueOfCell = Nvalue;
}
```

}

In addition, I would declare positionX, positionY, and valueOfCell as private instead of public and use getter and setter instead.

Answer (score 0):

import Cell into your Game class at the top of your file for Cell.java:

```
import Cell;
```

Give it the fully qualified package name if Cell outside the package Game is in.

Comment: All classes are in the same package but it still does not "see" the Cell class

Comment: @anne I see in your code there is a getCell() method that is supposed to return a Cell object, but doesn't actually do so. Try to return a Cell object in that code and see if that does anything.

Comment: actually it's not like it doesnt see it i just get "unexpected token" error when it comes to these two for loops and it treats int i like class? Cause it gives an error unknown class for i

Comment: @anne look at my comment above yours

Comment: mmm i saw it but before i will finish that method i shall first create a 2d array of object (make it work cause now it doesnt want to compile) and then i can try with returning smth from it